# Web Logic 9.2 redployment issues

Tags: ant, build.xml, java-5, weblogic9.x, redeploy

So, After a lot of R&D I've still not been able to find a fix to my issue. I'm working on an enterprise app. It's using WebLogic 9.2, ANT and JDK 1.5.

The issue: "weblogic.Deployer$DeployerException: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Unable to connect to 't3://{localhost}:7001': invalid type code: 31. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that the credentials are correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server"

The "fixes" I've attempted:

- *The client JVM was in version 1.6, the server was in 1.5. To fix the issue, the client must be run with Java 1.5. Possibly, the client may laucnh the JVM with the option -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true*

I did this in startWeblogic.cmd & setDomainenv.cmd: **set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true** in C:\bea\weblogic92\samples\domains\wl_server

This did not work. Then I attempted,

- *The error goes away after deleting the weblogic’s cache located under Admin server or managed server* and on another page *The error goes away after deleting the weblogic’s cache located under ${YOURDOMAIN_HOME}\servers\AdminServer\tmp_WL_user*

So I went to: C:\bea\weblogic92\samples\domains\wl_server\servers\examplesServer and deleted the cache folder.

However, this did not work aswell.

Then, I attempted

*- Please check below points and apply configurations as required:
1) Ensure hostname, port and credentials are correct
2) Enable tunneling as required in weblogic console
- Login to weblogic console 
- Environmnets -> Server -> Select Sever
- Go to Protcols -> HTTP
- Check Enable Tunneling
- Apply changes
- No restart required*

Which also didn't end up working. I mean, I'm not stupid, so I tried a various combination and fixes. Tried adding the project with correct versions and such. So, I'm hoping someone here has seen or faced this so will be able to help me.

I've attached my code where I want the **redeploy** to happen from my build.xml

```
        <!-- Build everything -->
<taskdef name="wldeploy" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="C:/bea/weblogic92/server/lib/weblogic.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>


    <target name="stopserver">
          <wlserver host="...." port="7001"
                     username="weblogic" password="weblogic"
                    action="shutdown" beahome="C:\bea\weblogic92" weblogichome="C:\bea\weblogic92\server" forceshutdown="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" >
        <wldeploy action="deploy" name="${ear-name}" 
            source="${deploy}/${ear-name}" user="weblogic" 
            nostage="true" password="weblogic" verbose="true" 
            adminurl="t3://....:7001" />
    </target>

    <target name="redeploy" depends="build-all">
        <wldeploy action="redeploy" name="${ear-name}" 
            source="${deploy}/${ear-name}" user="weblogic" 
            password="weblogic" verbose="true" 
            adminurl="t3://....:7001" />
    </target>

    <target name="undeploy">
        <wldeploy action="undeploy" name="${ear-name}" 
            failonerror="false" user="weblogic" password="weblogic" 
            verbose="true" adminurl="t3://....:7001" />
    </target>
```

Look forward to your answers,

Thanks

Comment: Also, FYI, I'm able to deploy using the console.

Comment: Tried it on a differnt computer with same requirments. Running into the same issue. :(

Comment: Did you find a solution?